# Chrome extension id algorithm for local folder

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What is the algorithm of extension id in Chrome for local folders?
For instance, given extension inside /usr/mychromeextension , how I calculate its extension id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [source code in id_util.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/crx_file/id_util.cc?l=42&rcl=0bee6f0baaa916721773d58c068c03012dfce5cb):

1. SHA256 of the full path without trailing slash is calculated as a lowercase hex string.

   - in Windows the drive letter is uppercased if the path starts with one
   - in Windows UTF-16 encoding is used for the file path
2. the first 32 hex digits of the hash string are used
3. each hex digit is mapped from `0`..`f` to `a`..`p` range:
   the decimal value of each hex digit is added to the ASCII code of lowercase `a` (97 decimal)

   > We use the characters 'a'-'p' instead of '0'-'f' to avoid ever having a completely numeric host, since some software interprets that as an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If you run MacOS or Linux, you can calculate extension ID for local project:

```
echo -n /full/path/to/extension | openssl dgst -sha256 | head -c32 | tr 0-9a-f a-p
```

Where:

- `/full/path/to/extension` – absolute path to extension folder (without trailing slash)
- `shasum` – calculates SHA256
- `head` – takes first 32 characters
- `tr` maps hex `0..f` to alphabet `a..p`